# Angular - Decoupling parent and child module routes completely

Tags: angular, angular6

In angular application, to lazyload a module, we need to use the following way in routes,

```
{
        path: '',
        component: MyLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'child', loadChildren: './child/child.module#ChildModule' }
        ]
}
```

In this way, for every new module, this routes file will get an update. Is there any way that i could still use child module without registering it in the 'children' array of parent module? So that development of a feature module will not have any effect on the parent module.

Comment: Why not create a separate routes file which exports an array of the routes? You can then import those routes into your parent module. Any changes therefore, would go to the routes file and leave your module unchanged.

Comment: that's already done, but the question is in the future if i have another feature module, then `{ path: 'child2', loadChildren: './child2/child2.module#Child2Module' }` should be added to parent routes again which i want to avoid. What i need is an option for a parent module to identify their children automatically based on the url and available feature modules

Answer (score 0):

**You have to create Module File for child Component.**

For Example: You have two component

1. Account Component
2. Dashboard Component

**For Account Component : You have to create one account.module file to set routes for Account Component like this way.**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'account',
                component: AccountComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [AccountComponent]
})
```

**For Dashboard Component : You have to create one dashboard.module file to set routes for Dashboard Component like this way.**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardComponent,
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [DashboardComponent]
})
```

**In the Main routes file or APP Modules file you have to import modules.**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'},
    {path: 'account', loadChildren: './modules/account/account.module#AccountModule'}
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DashboardModule,
        AccountModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [

    ]
})
```